# Update query depend on result of sub query Execution Doesnt Stop even after long time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Following is my Query unable to update when Executed table gets lock Execution does not stop even for an hour.

```
update Employees 
set Status = 'Close'
where statusid IN (select statusid 
                from MyView 
                where DownloadedDate ='2014-07-27 00:00:00.000')
```

here Employee contains 3,00,000 of records and 
     Subquery return 1,50,000 Empid

i tried for 2 days with various ways but unable to solve it 
Even Using Cursor its not working

Comment: What is "lakhs"?  Also, do you mean that the subquery returns 1.5 million rows?  Is there an index on Empid on the Employees table?

Comment: Try to run the subquery separately?  If it's slow, that's probably due to the view, the code for which you have not shown us.

Comment: sub query returns 1,50,000 rows and there is no index on the column in where clause

Answer (score 0):

Try exists instead of in:

```
update Employees 
set Status = 'Close'
where exists(select 1 
                from MyView 
                where DownloadedDate ='2014-07-27 00:00:00.000'
                      and MyView.statusid = Employees.statusid)
```

If it doesn't work, you should create a table instead the view, to find out is there any problem of the view?

Use query plan to analyze the steps and costs . [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)